# BC30035 Visual Basic AND VB.NET Syntax error

Tags: vb.net, syntax-error

Hy, i have a problem with my script, and i got this error information : BC30035 Syntax error. 
How can i fix it?

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim flag As Boolean = Me.RadioButton1.Checked
    If flag Then
        Dim text As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
        Dim text2 As String = ""
        Dim mD As MD5 = MD5.Create()
        Try
            text2 = Form1.GetMD5Hash(mD, text)
        Finally
            flag = (mD IsNot Nothing)
            If flag Then
Error   ------> (CType(mD, IDisposable)).Dispose() Then
                End If
        End Try
        Me.TextBox2.Text = text2
    End If
    flag = Me.RadioButton2.Checked
    If flag Then
        Dim text3 As String = Me.TextBox1.Text
        Dim bytes As Byte() = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text3)
        Dim text4 As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
        Me.TextBox2.Text = text4
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Remove the Then after your Dispose().

Comment: And the parentheses around the `CType` statement

Comment: Do you have a problem typing directly _mD.Dispose()_ ?

Comment: A `Using` block would result in simpler code.  By the way, *no one* has all the error codes memorized - read the words and share them

Comment: @NoAlias I have deleted, but still there was a mistake

Comment: @ProGrammer wow, thanks. problem solved :)

Comment: @Steve Yeah, that my problem.

Thanks all for help me.... Problem Solved

Comment: @Plutonix if i use "Using" i got error : 'Using' operand of type 'MD5' must implement 'System.IDisposable'